# Angular http post to return data back through service to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-services

I Want to return data (@@identity) from sql server through the service to the component

The Web api is definitely being called and sending data back.

However, since I am new to Angular 2/4  ( i was used to angular 1 )  i would normally just do  `return` on a service , and set a variable or object to the caller.

Currently this is what I am doing

**Component**

```
this.trackerFormService.addSession();  // CURRENT
```

but since the value is a single id,  like  5,   shouldn't i create something in typescript to retrieve it?

```
this.myId = this.trackerFormService.addSession();    // ???
```

**Then in the Service**

```
private _url = 'http://localhost:60696/api/tracker';

addSession() { 
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({}), options).catch(this.handleError).subscribe();

}
```

Now for the above to pass the ID from the service (addSession() method back to component, shouldn't i do a `return` ?

```
return this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({}), options).catch(this.handleError).subscribe();
```

but will that truly even work?

Web api (.net core )  looks like this

```
return Created($"api/sessiontrackers/{sessionTracker.Id}", sessionTracker);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will surely help you with making post call to web api

https://dheerajsroy.wixsite.com/dheerajkumar/single-post/2017/09/07/How-to-make-Post-Call-in-Angular-2

**In your service**

```
 return this.http.post(Url, JSON.stringify(data), requestOptions)
              .map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

**In your Component**

```
this.service.addSession(this.data).subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data) // Data which is returned by call
      },
      error => { console.log(error); // Error if any
      },
      ()=> // Here call is completed. If you wish to do something 
      // after call is completed(since this is an asynchronous call), this is the right place to do. ex: call another function
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return the `Observable` from your `addSession`, without `.subscribe`

```
addSession() { 
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({}), options).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And because this is an asynchronous call, `subscribe` to your observable in your component and when it will finish the call, assign the value to your `myId`.

```
this.trackerFormService.addSession().subscribe(result => this.myId = result);
```

Comment: I seem to get too much data,  like  `Response with stataus: 201 Create for URL ...`     how can i have the component subscriber to properly do a console.log of the data ?